# Font Awesome fa-facebook rounded border

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Hello there I've got a problem with Font Awesome social icons.
I used border-radius:50%; to keep the border rounded, it works for all except facebook which is acutally higher than other icons and look oval instead of rounded... Here is how it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AajpO.png

HTML:

```
<ul class="actions">
    <li><a href="#" class="fa solo fa-facebook social"><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fa solo fa-twitter social"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fa solo fa-youtube social"><span>Youtube</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="fa solo fa-google-plus social"><span>Google+</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.social{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid white;
    padding:30px;
}
```

Comment: If you want them all to be the same size, then you should not let the size of the icon character determine the width and height of each element, but set a width and height explicitly (this will need `display:inline-block` as well for width and height to take effect).

Comment: Works perfect with display:inline-block; width:100px; height:100px; padding:30px; Thank you very much :)

Comment: Ok, added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them all to be the same size, then you should not let the size of the icon character determine the width and height of each element, but set a width and height explicitly (this will need `display:inline-block` as well for width and height to take effect).